# android -recycleview using notifyItemRemoved not working properly

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I'm using recycleview for populating my items.  I'm trying to use notifyItemRemoved to remove an item from my recycleview  but it does not hide the row and it doesn't notify the adapter .this is my adapter code :

```
public class CatsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CatsAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<CatItems> list;

    public CatsAdapter(Context context, List<CatItems> feedItemList) {
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.list = feedItemList;
    }


    public void addAll(List<CatItems> catItems) {
        if (this.list == null) {
            this.list = catItems;
        } else {
            this.list.addAll(catItems);
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        notifyItemInserted(list.size());
    }

    public void remove(int pos) {
        this.list.remove(pos);
        notifyItemRemoved(pos);
        notifyItemRangeChanged(pos, getItemCount()-pos);
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parrent, int i) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row_grid2, parrent, false);
        MyViewHolder holder = new MyViewHolder(view);
        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder viewHolder, final int position) {
        CatItems item = list.get(position);
            viewHolder.del.setTag(item.getId());
            viewHolder.del.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    adapter.remove(position);
                }
            });

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        if (list == null)
            return 0;
        else
            return list.size();
    }


    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        ImageView img, ten, five,del;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
            del = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.del);
        }

    }
}
```

Where is the problem ?

Comment: Have you checked if `remove()` is called or not? `adapter.remove(position);` seems suspicious to me. You can just call `remove(position)`. Also, make sure that you have passed correct range in `notifyItemRangeChanged`.

Comment: Could you provide the implementation of `OnClickListener` inside `MyViewHolder` class? The `OnClickListener` set inside onBindViewHolder does not seem to be working at all, so remove never gets called.

Comment: @SelçukCihan yes , I've loged and I'm sure that it calls